# Error H14 (No web processes running) deploy on Heroku

Tags: heroku, cloud

I try to create simple java App on Heroku.
I following step by step from http://samuelsharaf.wordpress.com/2011/11/06/create-a-simple-java-web-app-using-maven-and-upload-to-heroku/ to do it.

But when i try to deploy my app on heroku project i got error message like bellow when i try to view log

```
$ heroku logs -t
2012-07-10T02:15:14+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-07-10T02:15:27+00:00 heroku[api]: Add shared-database:5mb add-on by anwar@meruvian.org
2012-07-10T02:15:27+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by anwar@meruvian.org
2012-07-10T02:15:27+00:00 heroku[api]: Add MAVEN_OPTS, PATH, JAVA_OPTS config by anwar@meruvian.org
2012-07-10T02:15:27+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by anwar@meruvian.org
2012-07-10T02:15:28+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by anwar@meruvian.org
2012-07-10T02:15:28+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy cb1cfa2 by anwar@meruvian.org
2012-07-10T02:15:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to down
2012-07-10T02:15:28+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-07-10T02:16:51+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H14 (No web processes running) -> GET fierce-ocean-9944.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

This is my url on heroku :

http://fierce-ocean-9944.herokuapp.com/

What that error ?

How to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you properly create the `Procfile` in your project's root ?

Answer (score 27):

Have you tried scaling one of your process types? e.g. `heroku ps:scale web=1`

Or rather, check what's your current web count by using 'heroku ps'
See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling

Comment: This worked for me after initially deploying to heroku with an empty Procfile by accident. Adding to the Procfile after the fact didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I'm glad this question was asked. According to the documentation, it *seems* like the Procfile (where `web: node app.js` is declared) will *automatically* scale the number of Dynos to 1 upon a new release of the application.... however, it is necessary to go through the Heroku CLI and do `heroku ps:scal web=1` in order to start up that number of Dynos, as they are not started automatically. See [this section](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#visit-your-application) of the documentation.

Comment: It works but how did heroku create and deploy not work confuses me... Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I kept running into the same problem. The sample python application ran fine, but mine did not. I logged into the dashboard and noticed that the web dyno count for my app showed zero. So I bumped it up on the web gui (i.e., strech the slider widget until you get a non-zero count.) and that worked. My dashboard also showed the heroku ps:scale web=1 dyno at zero, and I left it as zero.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove your ProcFile and add again

```
git rm ProcFile –f
```

Again add the ProcFile to project

1. Check the spellings
2. Content structure of the ProcFile
3. ProcFile should not contain any extensions.

After that do the normal git procedure,

```
  git add . 
    
    git commit –m “add procfile” 
    
    git push heroku master
```

You will see,

**Procfile declares types -> web**

Instead of

**Procfile declares types -> (none)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a container to build a web application, create a `heroku.yaml` file like this in your project's root:

```
build:
docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
    web: [PUT YOUR CMD COMMAND IN DOCKERFILE HERE]
```

Then add `heroku.yaml` to git repository. You can remove `Procfile` (optional). Finally deploy your repository as the following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Add heroku.yml"
heroku stack:set container -a [YOUR APP NAME]
git push heroku master
```

If your are pushing to heroku for the first time, you should run `heroku git:remote -a [YOUR APP NAME]` before `git push heroku master`