# No web processes running Django in heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I was trying to deploy my application in heroku, but when i finally try to run my application in heroku I het in the browser this:

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

When i see my logs I get the next:

```
2013-08-31T19:53:30.672416+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by user@example.com
2013-08-31T19:53:30.700218+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by user@example.com
2013-08-31T19:58:41+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-08-31T20:04:12.967456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=cristowip.herokuapp.com fwd="189.137.81.39" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-08-31T20:04:13.161016+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=cristowip.herokuapp.com fwd="189.137.81.39" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-08-31T20:13:46+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation timed out: 904.285527871 seconds.
2013-08-31T20:22:52.646361+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=cristowip.herokuapp.com fwd="189.137.81.39" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-08-31T20:22:55.043424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=cristowip.herokuapp.com fwd="189.137.81.39" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-08-31T20:26:14+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-08-31T20:38:41+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-08-31T20:41:22+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation timed out: 908.241350492 seconds.
2013-08-31T20:49:24.238496+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=cristowip.herokuapp.com fwd="189.137.81.39" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-08-31T20:49:24.644910+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=cristowip.herokuapp.com fwd="189.137.81.39" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-08-31T20:53:47+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation timed out: 907.148099965 seconds.
2013-08-31T20:56:59+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-08-31T20:58:50.641624+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA resource by user@example.com
2013-08-31T20:58:50.658435+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by user@example.com
2013-08-31T20:58:50.742803+00:00 heroku[api]: Add DATABASE_URL config by user@example.com
2013-08-31T20:58:50.782484+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by user@example.com
2013-08-31T20:58:50.840509+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 78dba6c by user@example.com
2013-08-31T20:58:50.852187+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by user@example.com
2013-08-31T20:58:54+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-08-31T21:00:25.085053+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=cristowip.herokuapp.com fwd="189.137.81.39" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-31T21:00:24.751074+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=cristowip.herokuapp.com fwd="189.137.81.39" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-31T21:01:03.272614+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=cristowip.herokuapp.com fwd="189.137.81.39" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-31T21:01:03.815558+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=cristowip.herokuapp.com fwd="189.137.81.39" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-31T21:02:10.279054+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=cristowip.herokuapp.com fwd="189.137.81.39" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-31T21:03:25.381362+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=cristowip.herokuapp.com fwd="189.137.81.39" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-31T21:03:25.709121+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=cristowip.herokuapp.com fwd="189.137.81.39" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-31T21:03:45.285962+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=cristowip.herokuapp.com fwd="189.137.81.39" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
christian@christian-R480-R431-R481:~/Documentos/heroku/portafolio/venv$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error H14 (No web processes running) deploy on Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405826/error-h14-no-web-processes-running-deploy-on-heroku)

Answer (score 34):

Benjamin Manns' solution worked for me, though I needed one additional step as well.

According to [this](http://vibhurishi.blogspot.com/2013/02/heroku-error-h14-with-django.html), after the `Procfile` solution has been pushed, run the following:

**`heroku ps:scale web=1`**

website should load correctly now.

for more help pushing to a heroku git repo, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338551/how-does-git-push-heroku-master-know-where-to-push-to-and-how-to-push-to-a-dif)

Comment: when stating the file to run make sure it's relative to the Procfile. ex: if you want to run "manage.py" on root, the procfile entry should be web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT

Comment: If you mistakenly push a branch that doesn't have a Procfile, it will shut down all dynos. Once you push the branch with the Procfile, run the command above to restart.

Comment: You're my hero.

Comment: Getting error: Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).

Answer (score 14):

Add proc file and run following command

**`$ heroku ps:scale web=1`**

Comment: Also visit [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) for complete tutorial

Answer (score 9):

Have you gone through the [Heroku guide for setting up a Django application](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django)? What does your Procfile look like?

Your project should have a file named `Procfile` that should have contents similar to

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi
```

Answer (score 4):

Your **Procfile** must look like this (for python):

**web: python myApp.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT**

Answer (score 4):

If you are in python/django

```
heroku logs --tail
```

if you are unable to find the bug and fix then try doing,

First Run to see whether its working in herokus local

```
heroku local web
```

Mine was to specify the path of django wsgi.py file in Procfile

see their example https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started

The Procfile will look similar to this

```
web: gunicorn projectname.wsgi --log-file -
```

You may have to install gunicorn if not installed and add it to requirements.txt

Then Git add and commit, after that push to heroku

```
git push heroku master
```

Then scale your app

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following steps to make it work.

1) I had to move my Procfile to the outermost folder.

2) Then I had to change my Procfile to

```
web: gunicorn projectname.projectname.wsgi
```

3) Also in my wsgi file I had to change my settings path to

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'projectname.projectname.settings')
```

4) In my settings.py file I had to change my ROOT_URLCONF

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'projectname.projectname.urls'
```

5) In urls.py I had to change my path to

```
from projectname.applicationname import urls as app_urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(app_urls)),
]
```

6) Finally I did

```
git push heroku master
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

After making all these changes heroku worked like a charm. But it doesn't work locally on windows because I read somewhere windows doesn't have gunicorn.

When I tried `python projectname/manage.py runserver` locally it said

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projectname.projectname'
```

So for running it locally I've to revert all the steps above :P

Comment: In your settings.py add '127.0.0.1' to your allowed host

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was dynos configuration  error,i meant to say that if u re not premium member see whether dynos available for your app from heroku dashbord. this u can check by clicking on metrics,if you don't have one estimate it.
run command
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
push your code in master.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting application error
I checked heroku logs --tail , in ***desc="No web processes running"***
Mostly this occur due to Procfile, so inside Procfile I forgot to give space after "web:"

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi --log-file -
```

so check your Procfile{this file is to be created in root folder just inside project folder}

Answer (score 0):

Though it is already said but please do a check if the `Procfile`, `runtime.txt` and `requirements.txt` are in the outermost folder. (These files will be placed in the location of `manage.py`)

Answer (score 0):

My case was a little different. I had settled up everything and deployed my app on Heroku. I have deployed 3 4 python apps on Heroku previously. had Procfile and requirements.txt in root folder.

This time, I tried almost the whole every guide and StackOverflow answers but found nothing. Then just added a space after `web:` and `gunicorn` and it worked perfectly.

previously I was using `web:gunicorn wsgi:app`

I just changed that to `web: gunicorn wsgi:app` and It worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure your dynos is running otherwise you will get this above error also.
and then you have to manually start dynos on heroku, while heroku automatically start that for you but some time you have to do run manually on heroku.
**Click on a Configure dynos button** ==> **toggle the dynos button** and your dynos will start.

Answer (score 0):

Check your dyno's configuration in the Heroku dashboard. It might be the wrong app name before the wsgi module. I had an old project's app name instead of the one I tried to use:

```
web: gunicorn old_project_app.wsgi
```

Correct your Procfile and push it to Heroku. You might need to delete and recreate the file. It should then be like this in the dyno config:

```
web: gunicorn new_project_app.wsgi
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the spelling of the Procfile. Its supposed to be "Procfile" and not "procfile"