# After deploying an app on heroku there is an error

Tags: python, heroku

**This the error it is giving**

`2018-03-08T05:56:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: - Build succeeded`

`2018-03-08T05:57:34.534615+00:00 heroku[router]: - at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=infinite-ridge-58576.herokuapp.com request_id=b954f4aa-d2e3-4c98-80ce-3429d3c53ccc fwd="106.51.27.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

`2018-03-08T06:14:56.524496+00:00 heroku[router]: - at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=HEAD path="/" host=infinite-ridge-58576.herokuapp.com request_id=0563c94b-b490-4873-bcd1-de3edefbcba2 fwd="107.23.223.97" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http`

It is an python web app and the repo of it is [here](https://github.com/vipul-rao/csvbrain.git)

Even after using procfile like
***procfile:***
  `heroku ps:scale web=1`

and like this
***procfile:***
  `web: python app.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000`

Comment: You need to use a procfile, otherwise how is it supposed to know what to execute?

Comment: refer this > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552846/no-web-processes-running-django-in-heroku

Comment: @Burhan kahlid Even after using procfile i still have the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`code=H14 desc="No web processes running"`

You do not have a `web` process running. You need to ensure your `Procfile` 
 has the Dyno start command, i.e.:

`web: python app.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000`

and then, once deployed, you need to scale up your `web` process either via the application resources page of the Heroku Dashboard, or via the CLI command `heroku ps:scale web=1 -a your_app_name`