# Django App on heroku :Application Error

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

im trying to add my django application to heroku 
but everything went well  from migration and migrate commands  as well 
but when i tried to acess the site mxiondrf.herokuapp.com
there is a error called Application error 
here are my logs

```
2018-07-23T13:59:00.436425+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/api/li
st" host=mxiondrf.herokuapp.com request_id=5af5f21f-7e9b-4934-8e84-c6fca34477e1 fwd="103.49.121.34" dyno= connect= service=
 status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-23T13:59:00.862661+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favico
n.ico" host=mxiondrf.herokuapp.com request_id=5400e512-b34b-47a1-b7c7-d276cc311374 fwd="103.49.121.34" dyno= connect= servi
ce= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-23T13:59:03.975204+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host
=mxiondrf.herokuapp.com request_id=93d450c2-3a0a-44e1-83a7-e9e041c0b628 fwd="103.49.121.34" dyno= connect= service= status=
503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-23T13:59:04.353339+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favico
n.ico" host=mxiondrf.herokuapp.com request_id=580a6deb-a105-4442-a9fc-01ed7af39811 fwd="103.49.121.34" dyno= connect= servi
ce= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

proc file

```
web:gunicorn drf.wsgi
web: python website/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

settings.py allowed hosts

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['https://mxiondrf.herokuapp.com']
```

if anyone could help me in solving this issue 
any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552846/no-web-processes-running-django-in-heroku/22746975

Comment: Show your Procfile.

Comment: Show your Profile and add **ALLOWED_HOSTS = []** in your settings.py

Comment: @DanielRoseman edited the code and added allowed hosts as well

Comment: guys now when i checked again the error is 2018-07-23T14:37:30.216028+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mxiondrf.her
okuapp.com request_id=3226d7fe-a42e-4c41-8618-74f00206f5af fwd="103.49.121.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= pr

otocol=https