# Django website deploying to heroku. Application error

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, django-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my django website to heroku but I get an `Application Error` shown on the webpage. Looking at my logs using `heroku logs --tail` (what it tells me to do on webpage), I recieve an error

```
2019-07-27T06:14:34.046386+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=prremia.herokuapp.com request_id=20cd473d-50c2-43b6-892e-ce8f8981229d fwd="49.36.8.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-07-27T06:14:34.878053+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=prremia.herokuapp.com request_id=53c5e449-ba17-4e93-86f9-7b70eeb7e074 fwd="49.36.8.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I followed the instructions from [Django's docs](https://djangoguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django/deploy.html#heroku).

- Django 2.2.3
- Python 3.7.3
- Heroku-18

My webpage:
[image: What my webpage looks like]

Comment: This question has the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552846/no-web-processes-running-django-in-heroku or you can manually scale using the heroku doc , check https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling

Comment: @BidhanMajhi When trying to scale using `heroku ps:scale web=1` I get an error saying that they couldn't find the `web` process type. `Procfile` includes `web: gunicorn prremia.wsgi`

Comment: Go to your heroku dashboard, then in dashboard go to resources and check, if you have dynos.

Comment: @BidhanMajhi It tells me that I haven't made a `Procfile` but as I said above, I do, and I made sure to push it onto heroku.

Comment: Change your Procfile to `web: gunicorn prremia.wsgi --log-file -` And make sure you commit it.

Comment: @BidhanMajhi Nope, heroku still doesn't see a Procfile

Comment: @BidhanMajhi So, I restarted the entire process of deploying to heroku and scaling worked. But now I get an error saying that the app has crashed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your put your `Procfile` at the root of project along with `manage.py`. Also make sure you pushed the code from your project root.
Bind port dynamically in your `Procfile`. Here's an example:-

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT prremia.wsgi
```

`$PORT` is an environment variable. You must do scaling too.

Note: Make sure your project name exactly matches with `<project_name>.wsgi` in your `Procfile`.

Comment: I have made sure to push my Procfile and I did scale, but I how would I set this all up. (I mean the IP and `$PORT`)

Comment: Just put the content in your `Procfile` as I've mentioned.

Comment: So, 0.0.0.0.$PORT is the website?? Wut? I'm really confused

Comment: Google and read some basic stuff about ip address and you'll find out. For now try to build again putting those content in your `Procfile`.

Comment: Hmm, still not working. But I did find something interesting... The error also says `no module named 'prremia'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197083/discussion-between-md-khairul-basar-and-12944qwerty).

Answer (score 0):

Some time silly mistake is there when some one create Procfile as text file
so use the given command in your cmd to generate Prockfile:-

> echo "web: python app.py" > Procfile

// I hope my answer help you.