# Application error after deploying Django successfully

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deloy my django website to Heroku but after deploying successfully via Gilab CI/CD I get an `Application error`
Source for my django website: [source](https://gitlab.com/vuthehuyvnu/webping/tree/test-deploy)

My website URL [webping-server](https://webping-server.herokuapp.com/)

My webpage image: [image]

And log file as following:
[image]

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail, e.g. in this case by running `heroku logs`.

Comment: The link is right there on the error page: "check your logs for details"!!!! And the instructions to check them from the command line (`heroku logs --tail`).

Comment: okie, i'm trying

Comment: Similar question already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552846/no-web-processes-running-django-in-heroku

Comment: I have solved trouble, Djano 3.0 its remove django.utils.six, so I reintall Django 2.2.6

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

update your requirements

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt

git add .
git commit -m "requirements updated" 
git push heroku master
```