# Heroku-Django: code=H14 desc:"No web processes running"

Tags: django, heroku

Heroku logs

I am trying to deploy a django app on heroku, this is my first app which I am deploying on heroku, the build succeeded but when I run the URL, It says application error and logs shows following thing.

```
2020-07-29T07:58:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ketanpatil3106@
gmail.com
2020-07-29T07:58:59.203607+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 26b25759 by user ketanpatil310
6@gmail.com
2020-07-29T07:58:59.203607+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user ketanpatil
3106@gmail.com
2020-07-29T07:59:07.261443+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=newtonnation.herokuapp.com request_i
d=debda95e-c51d-4090-87a9-73102c5c9411 fwd="106.193.222.48" dyno= connect= servi
ce= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-29T07:59:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-07-29T07:59:10.136919+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=newtonnation.herokuapp.co
m request_id=50db9f9b-2e03-4465-b3ba-f851612f3db8 fwd="106.193.222.48" dyno= con
nect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-29T07:59:12.539684+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=newtonnation.herokuapp.com request_i
d=22f644fb-4d6f-48ed-a34f-f35d5dd41033 fwd="106.193.222.48" dyno= connect= servi
ce= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-29T07:59:13.903721+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=newtonnation.herokuapp.co
m request_id=3dfff95c-dd3c-4590-ad22-2c673a9ec5b9 fwd="106.193.222.48" dyno= con
nect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-29T08:04:38.784712+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=newtonnation.herokuapp.com request_i
d=6e61e063-8575-4236-9d87-a1af42058b82 fwd="106.193.222.48" dyno= connect= servi
ce= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-29T08:04:41.381297+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=newtonnation.herokuapp.co
m request_id=ab3bd0e2-5396-4c63-9735-9d0a30f54013 fwd="106.193.222.48" dyno= con
nect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn PHYSICS_COMMUNITY.wsgi
```

I've tried running `heroku ps:scale web=1` but it returned `Couldn't find that process type (web).`

Please help me

Comment: The syntax for defining a process is `<process type>: <command>` you are missing `:` in your Procfile

Comment: Tried already, doesn't make any change

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552846/no-web-processes-running-django-in-heroku

Answer (score 0):

if it is successfully built the problem is starting the app. heroku by default checks for "start" script in package.json.

since you put this `gunicorn PHYSICS_COMMUNITY.wsgi` on procfile, I assume this is the start command for the production.

you can either set up start script in package json, to me it is the easiest way

```
   "start":"gunicorn PHYSICS_COMMUNITY.wsgi"
```

or i you want to have Procfile, the problem is you left a blank after "web".

```
 web:gunicorn PHYSICS_COMMUNITY.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Profile is on root directory