# "No web processes running" Error on Heroku , Deploying Fastapi

Tags: python, windows, heroku, fastapi

I am trying to host FASTAPI apis on Heroku, but I keep facing this error

```
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=myapp-api.herokuapp.com request_id=09d8bd62-bcf7-4738-a747-fb3cdd8cd7f7 fwd="103.99.148.171" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myapp-api.herokuapp.com request_id=92d2cfd5-c0d8-4696-9e79-8f0bb7231bce fwd="103.99.148.171" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

After referring all the similar post ,
[like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552846/no-web-processes-running-django-in-heroku)
I found that
`heroku ps:scale web=1`
could work , but my issue is

1. There is no mention of where to run this command.
2. Should this be added it to my proctfile ?
3. I tried running it in the Heroku `Run Console` on the web. but it returned `bash: heroku: command not found`
4. Since Gunicorn ( Required by Fastapi ) is not supported in windows, and thus I am also unable to do `heroku run local`

My proctfile looks like this

`web: gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app -p $PORT`

My full error log

```
2022-07-21T08:53:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-07-21T08:53:26.112645+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=myapp-api.herokuapp.com request_id=9efd5f28-4aa3-4aac-91b0-bc89b8da1d1b fwd="103.99.148.171" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T08:53:26.949447+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myapp-api.herokuapp.com request_id=b03f8ca4-63e3-48c7-9349-2339fa0a4dc7 fwd="103.99.148.171" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T08:54:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user dummyuserid
2022-07-21T08:54:35.485193+00:00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user dummyuserid
2022-07-21T08:54:35.485193+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 6d456f91 by user dummyuserid
2022-07-21T08:54:37.460184+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to down
2022-07-21T08:54:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-07-21T08:55:08.908036+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=myapp-api.herokuapp.com request_id=5f961c83-9dfd-4346-9511-420cbd0bee6e fwd="103.99.148.171" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-21T08:55:09.686828+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myapp-api.herokuapp.com request_id=062ef29f-c702-4963-8eb6-4ec09a9c1d7d fwd="103.99.148.171" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: 1. In Heroku CLI, you are correct in point 3. - 2. No. - 3a. You need to install the Heroku CLI in order to use it. 3b. You can use the Heroku Dyno site. Your app > Resources > there should be your Procfile and you need to reenable that. - 4. Gunicorn is not required and you should start your app without that since a very common problem is that many projects are not compatible with running the same project multiple times. - 5. You should provide the entire log from the moment you enable your web process, see 3.

Comment: Note that the `Procfile` must be named `Procfile` _exactly_. There is no `t`, it must have a capital `P`, and it cannot have any extension. You have typed `proctfile` at least twice here. (This is unlikely to be related to your problem, just an important note.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the error to be in the Procfile.
Changed the Procfile to

`web uvicorn main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-5000}`

and then it worked.